# Chrome Cast Time out Exception

Tags: google-chrome, exception, time, casting, out

I am receiving onError: {"code":"timeout","description":"Timeout at extension","details":null}
 i have followed hello world example from github.

**1.** i am unable to get a session. i have tried with my app id and with default cast id. but all it vein.

This is the piece of code that threw exception.

```
{

 if (session!=null) {

    session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);

  }

  else {

    chrome.cast.requestSession(function(e) {
        session = e;
        session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
      }, onError);
  } 
}
```

**2.** i am unable to understand the namespace. what it should be for a simple hello world app.